# If a user is not opening the Android application for few days, then why it stops receiving push/remote notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I am working on the android application, which is useful to send push/alerts to its users for the emergency situations like severe weather, missing persons, colds, floods, earthquakes, etc warnings.

Recently, I have started receiving the complaint from the app users about not receiving the push notifications if they are not opening the app regularly(i.e rarely opens the app).

To ensure the push notification delivery(In case if the app gets entered in the App standby "Rare" bucket due to not opening the app on the regular basis), My mobile app server is sending the high-priority push notifications using firebase, and even then app is not receiving the push-notification.

Kindly help and share if there is any specific service provided by Android for such type of emergency service-related apps through which timely delivery of push notifications is possible to the app.

Comment: I think this happens when your app is hibernated (Force Stooped), i always do hibernation of my mobile app to prevent battery drainage, and to improve mobile performance. if this is not the case then i am interested in the solutions.

Comment: Thank you @ManishAhire! I guess most probably you are right, but actually, still in this case, I am thinking that might be Android should have some kind of special services for the emergency-service-related apps to ensure the push-notification delivery and for that I am looking for.